# How to deprecate the companion object of a case class?

Tags: scala, deprecated, companion-object

I noticed that if a case class is deprecated its companion object is not.

```
scala> @deprecated case class A(x: Int)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
defined class A

scala> A(0)
res0: A = A(0)

scala> new A(0)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: A = A(0)
```

I would like to get a warning for `A(0)` exactly as I get it for `new A(0)`. Should I define the companion object explicitly and deprecate it ? Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I define the companion object explicitly and deprecate it ?

Apparently so! According to https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2799, it should be deprecated automatically (and it makes sense to me), but it doesn't seem to be anymore.

Comment: I tried this: `@deprecated("foo","") case class A(x: Int); @deprecated("bar","") object A`, but calling `A(0)` still doesn't give a deprecation warning.